# Permission denied (publickey) when cloning while `git push` runs fine

Tags: git, bitbucket

We are cloning a Git repo on Bitbucket to a local drive and comes with an error:

```
Internal error: 

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It seems that there is problem with public key. However the `git push` command runs successfully without error:

```
git push origin my-branch
```

This indicates that there is no problem for local computer to talk with Git repo on the Bitbucket with ssh. We delete the repo on Bitbucket and re-create it and the problem is the same. Where is the problem coming from?

### Update

URL used for cloning in Apatana IDE is `git@bitbucket.org:myloging/mygit.git`. However running `git clone` in command line is fine.

Comment: What URL are you using for your `git clone` operation?  What URL is configured in the existing remote (use `git remote -v`)?

Comment: Ok you said that cloning with the IDE is raising the error right? So maybe your IDE is not able to find the corresponding ssh-key. I am not experienced with Apatana IDE, but for me it sounds like your IDE is having problems with this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

**If the correct identities are not loaded onto the shell:**
Does `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` work for you? If not, check whether any identities are loaded using `ssh-add -l`. If you find that the correct identities are not loaded then use `ssh-add -l <path to private key such as ~/.ssh/id_rsa>`. Again try `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`. This time it should work.